# Move slider input range thumb in relation to mouse down position

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, dom

How can I move the HTML 5 input range thumb without having to drag it, but instead dragging over the slider itself, in an arbitrary position. Much like one could do using [TouchOSC](https://hexler.net/docs/touchosc-controls-reference#faderrotary/%20TouchOSC) when choosing Response:relative.

I'm talking about the simplest input range slider:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Data Jam!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>jamming</h1>
        <input type="range">
    </body>
</html>
```

So, instead of moving the thumb clicking on it.
one could [click and drag anywhere in the slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Xkm.png)

Normally by clicking anywhere in the slider, the thumb jumps to that position. Maybe this is something rather easy to prevent, but then one have to click directly on the thumb, which sometimes, specially when using touch-screen e.g in mobiles, can be not so ergonomic.
Moving the thumb by clicking anywhere in the slider can ensure that the values will change smoothly, and the ui will be ergonomic.

I hope this is possible without having to inflate the code.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, but more importantly what have you tried?  Do you have any basic code?

Comment: I edit it to make it as clear as I can. Please tell me if something is missing, this is my first post in Stackoverflow, I'm still learning the protocols

Comment: The question is much better now, yes.  You may want to play around with attaching mouse down/move/up listeners on the input element.